# Comparisons on numbers and strings in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In console:

```
1.9.3p547 :010 > my_s = 00013.to_s
 => "11"
1.9.3p547 :011 > my_s = 00013.to_i
 => 11
1.9.3p547 :012 > 13.to_s
 => "13"
1.9.3p547 :013 > 13.to_i
 => 13
```

Why this difference in treatment?  How can comparisons be made between string values that are fundamentally numbers but that have been padded with zeros?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You wrote `00013`, with leading zeros.  In Ruby (and a lot of other languages), integer literals starting with zeros are treated as octal (base 8), so the number you typed (when written in decimal) is really 8 + 3 = 11.

To answer the second part of your question:  If you have a string like `'00013'`, you can just call `#to_i` on it and Ruby will actually convert it to 13 (in decimal).  So that should allow you to make comparisons.

Comment: If you want to get `"13"` from `00013`, knowing it is octal, you can do `00013.to_s(8)`. You can then call `to_i` on that if you want an int.

Comment: @ptd added a comment that is most useful.  Having an array, some padded others **not**, would applying `to_s(8)` have ill effects on the unpadded?

Comment: @Jerome yes, it would have ill effects. If you want to know what will happen, you should use `irb` to see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby's `Integer` class, leading zeroes are not stored.

Leading zeroes are number literals and are interpreted like so

`Octal`: 0, 0o

`Hexadecimal`: 0, 0x

`Binary`: 0b

`Decimal`: 0d

'00013' has three leading zeroes, and matches the format `0o`. IRB treats these numbers as octal(base 8)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any "string values that are fundamentally numbers but that have been padded with zeros" in your example. If you did, it would actually work how you expect:

```
"00013".to_i
# => 13
```

You have a number literal in your example that has been padded with zeroes. As the other answers say, this is treated as an octal representation by ruby.

But if you actually had a string representation of a number, padded with zeroes, it works fine, just call #to_i on it.